# Eulerian Circuit Recursion statement resetting my list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def eulerian_circuit(graph):

    trail = []

    for edge in graph:
        graph.sort()
        a,b = edge 
        if not trail:
            trail.append(a)
            trail.append(b)
            graph.remove((a,b))
            print(graph)
        if a == trail[-1]:
            trail.append(b)
            graph.remove((a,b))
            print(graph)
        if not graph:
            return trail

    eulerian_circuit(graph)            
    return trail,graph           

eulerian_circuit([('a','b'), ('b','c'), ('a','f'), ('b','d'), ('d','f'), ('b','e'), ('e','g'), ('c','g'), ('f','g'), ('f','h'), ('g','h')])
```

My problem is that when I call the recursion eulerian_circuit(graph)

my trail resets at the top with trail = []. How do I get around this?

(code is unfinished for circuit answer, still have to implement when theres one edge left to connect back to the starting vertex... and have to figure out other errors i'm sure will come up. new to python)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `trail` as a parameter to the sub-call of `eulerian_circuit`.

Give the function a default value of `None` for `trail` so that you can know if it's the top level call:

```
def eulerian_circuit(graph, trail=None):
    if trail is None:
        trail = []
    ...
    eulerian_circuit(graph, trail):
```

Usage:

```
eulerian_circuit([('a','b'), ('b','c'), ('a','f')])
```

Comment: Thank you.. seem to be getting a "maximum recursion" exceeded error now. I've tried adding if b = trail[-1] then append(a) and remove((a,b)) but that doesn't seem to work either, that tells me that (a,b) isn't there to remove.

Comment: Well, you have no condition that you don't call `eulerian_circuit` again, and again, and again...

Comment: I don't know anything about the Eulerian circuit algorithm, I'm just helping with coding issues.

Comment: You're iterating over `graph` whilst modifying it, which is asking for trouble.

Comment: Not really sure how else I would do this problem. What I am trying to do is find a path that uses edges only once (vertices can be used more than once) and start and end at the same vertex.

Comment: That's a different question for other people to answer (and I'm the only one who'll get updated with your messages if you comment on my answer, so you're limiting yourself to a small pool of workers (c:). I've answered what you were originally asking.